# Code Repetition

Tags: android, android-activity

I have to write a code to show "internet not available" dialogue box in few class files. As far as i know i need to write this code onCreate method only, but my concern is, **code repetition.** The code is as follows

```
onCreate()
{
  if(isNetworkStatusAvialable (getApplicationContext())) 
    {
        showAlertDialog(HomeActivity.this, "Internet Connection",
                    "You have internet connection", true);
    } 
    else
    {
        showAlertDialog(HomeActivity.this, "No Internet Connection",
                    "You don't have internet connection.", true);
    }
}//End of oncreate

showAlertDialog(................... )
 {

 }
```

In few class files the same code will be repeted. To avoid this, if i write separate class file and extend as "Extends" then i worried that onCreate method will be override through out the required class files, which consists of other things.

Any suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

The application will crash with a `SuperNotCalledException` if an Activity overrides `onCreate()` without calling through to `super.onCreate()`, so as long as each Activity extends your base Activity you can be guaranteed that your implementation will be called.